# Find records that have a minimum of 25 child records greater than 0 - LAMBDA

Tags: c#, lambda

I' m trying to limit results to only those that contains at least 25 records with a loadWeight greater than zero. (First 25 using Take() is ok in this case).

```
proxyList = proxyList
  .Where(x => x.Load.LoadDetailList
     .Take(25)
     .Where(y => y.loadWeight > 0)
  .ToList();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `Where(y => y.loadWeight > 0)` *first* to filter out the records to count; `Skip` *24* records and check if there're `Any` records so far (i.e. *25* or more records):

```
proxyList = proxyList
  .Where(x => x.Load.LoadDetailList
     .Where(y => y.loadWeight > 0)
     .Skip(24) 
     .Any()) // Any: do we have 25th item?
  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
proxyList = proxyList
    .Where(x => x.Load.LoadDetailList
        .Where(y => y.loadWeight > 0)
        .Count() > 25)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Your solution is correct (but probably it should be `.Count() >= 25`), but may be *inefficient*: what if `Count()` returns `123456789 `?

Comment: Thanks much. In this case max records will not exceed 50.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Where` function takes a predicate, so you need to return a boolean. You want to check that the count of records matching your condition is over 25.

```
proxyList.Where(x => x.Load.LoadDetailTest.Count(y => y.LoadWeight > 0) > 25));
```

Comment: Being *correct* your solution can be *inefficient*: what if `Count(y => y.LoadWeight > 0)` returns `10000000`?